# Manage click on a mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to manage click on a mesh (cube) to do some processing stuff.

```
    var cubeFor3D = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(40,80,40),img3D);

    scene.add(cubeFor3D);
    //
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
    //
    animate();
         //Track the click on cube3d
    cubeFor3D.on('click', function(){

          // response to click...
          console.log('you have clicked on cube 2D');

 });
```

When running, i got this error on the web console:

```
TypeError: cubeFor3D.on is not a function
```

In the API documentation, it's shown to do like this:

```
mesh.on('click',..
```

But i guess i should replace `mesh` by my mesh real name. Seems i am going wrong. help please.

I am including the API JS in my file: `<script src='threex.domevent.js'></script>`

Comment: What scrips are you including? Do you have `threex.domevent.js`? It is not a default feature of three.js

Comment: Oh yeah, i am including it: `<script src='threex.domevent.js'></script>
`

Comment: Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but, if you add this to the begging of the init function it should work:

THREE.Object3D._threexDomEvent.camera(camera);

In fact I normally put in straight after scene = new THREE.Scene();